# How i can update sql record by checkbox in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP so I faced a problem, I got these rows in MySQL

```
+---+--------------+
|ID |  published   |
+---+--------------+
| 1 |    TRUE      |
| 2 |    FALSE     |
| 3 |    TRUE      |
+---+--------------+
```

For example, I want to update ID no. 2 into "TRUE" with a checkbox:

```
<?php 

$host="localhost";  
$username="root";  
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="chek_box_test"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>

<?php 

$id = $_GET['id'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = $id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
?>
<form method="post" action="checkbox_test.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="publish" <?php
if($row['publish'] == TRUE){
     echo "checked='checked'";
}
?>
/>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"></form><?php } ?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $publish = ($_POST['publish'] == 1) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET publish = '$publish' WHERE id =$id");
}
?>
```

My problem is if I check that PHP it only give me 'FALSE' value. I want that if I check and click submit it will give me "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Please help me to do this. Any useful advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your table field `published` actually hold? Tinyint (0|1), enum('yes','no') or enum('TRUE','FALSE'). You are mixing up `true` and `yes`.

Comment: oh sorry its a mistake` it was boolian number instaed of yes or no

Comment: There is no such thing as a boolean number in mysql. What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: Ok its tiny or enum. Pick one of them. Better if it is enum('TRUE','FALSE')

Comment: If it is tinyint 'yes' and 'no' are all mapped to 1, which is not what you want.

Comment: Ok. I want that output result would be enum data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your input field is missing:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="publish" value="1" <?php
if($row['publish'] == 'yes'){
     echo "checked='checked'";
}
?>
/>
```

To solve the error 'Undefined index publish' you could change

```
echo $publish = ($_POST['publish'] == 1) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

to:

```
$publish = FALSE;
if(isset($_POST['publish']) and $_POST['publish']==1) {
  $publish = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Its working. Its give me true value by check and uncheck. But 1 more problem have. Next time when i uncheck and click update button it show a error. And the error is 'Undefined index publish in my file name on line 34

Answer (score 0):

Mention the value="TRUE"

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="publish"  <?php
   if($row['publish'] == 'yes'){
    echo "checked='checked' ";
    echo "value='TRUE'";
   }
   ?>
   />
```

Comment: plz see my question code one more time and First ans also